# A question regarding maximum likelihood conditional on observed and unobserved variables

Tags: distributions, multiple-regression, maximum-likelihood, stata, latent-variable

Please consider the following likelihood function,
$$
L(\theta)=\int_{\Re^u} f(y|x,u,\theta)h(u|\xi)\partial u,
$$
where $y$ is a vector of observed dependent variables, $u$ is a vector of unobserved, normally distributed variables, and $x$ is a vector of observed exogenous variables, assumed to be taken as given. $\theta,\xi$ are parameters.

My main question is this: Does this definition of the likelihood function imply $Cov(x,u)=0$? (Or that $u$ is not a function of $x$, if this covariance is not defined when $x$ is treated as given.)

My confusion stems mainly from the statement that $x$ is to be "taken as given". I assume that implies that no (marginal) density function for $x$ exists. I don't know if the notation above is sloppy, but the concept of a conditional density involving the non-random vector $x$ still seems to exist, otherwise the definition of $f(y|x,u)$ wouldn't make sense, right? But then I'd imagine that the above factorization comes from
$$
g(y,u|x)=f(y|x,u)h(u|x)
$$
(with parameters left out for brevity), but the integration at the top above involves the marginal distribution of $u$.

The background of my question is that Stata's command "gsem" is based on the above likelihood function, and the documentation states that "[c]ovariances between latent exogenous and observed exogenous variables [... are a]ssumed to be nonzero. Cannot be estimated or constrained because this covariance is not among the identified parameters of the generalized SEM" (p. 48 of the SEM manual).

Any help would be much appreciated! Disclaimer: This is a cross-post; I have posted a [similar question](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1328131-does-stata-s-gsem-command-assume-zero-covariance-between-latent-and-observed-exogenous-variables) at Stata's forum.

Comment: **A:** Defining a joint density as $f(y|x,u,\theta)h(u|\xi)$ conditional on $x$ means that indeed $u$ is independent of $x$. Hence in particular $\text{cov}(u,x)=0$ if both $u$ and $x$ are real variables.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you, this is exactly the reasoning why I have doubts regarding the statement in Stata's documentation. But as I said, would this reasoning change under the assumption that $x$ is to be taken as given? (Are covariances or conditional densities involving $x$ actually meaningful in this context?) Or could there be other reasons that allow me to write $h(u)$ instead of $h(u|x)$ and still have $u$ be a function of $x$?